# Some zip codes not returning the expected results from the Google Geocode API in Australia

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

2009 for example is a [valid zip code in Sydney](https://auspost.com.au/locate/post-office/NSW/Pyrmont/2009), but if you search the Geocode API for 2009, australia, then it [returns](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2009,australia) a set of coordinates in the outback.

You can test this by adding the -25.274398,133.775136 coordinates on [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse).

Only searching for [2009, Sydney](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2009,sydney) returns the expected results. I'm pretty sure zip codes are unique in Australia, so why wouldn't 2009, Australia return the same results as 2009, Sydney?

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: First line of the documentation: *Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739)* so it's not a zip code search engine.

Comment: Geonames.org has a [postal code search service](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#postalCodeSearch) which [returns](http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=2009&country=AU&username=demo) what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

4-digit and 5-digit postal codes are hard to find in the Geocoding API, sometimes even with country name, because they are surprisingly ambiguous in a worldwide context. See https://issuetracker.google.com/75985322 and https://issuetracker.google.com/73030863 for more details.

There is a workaround there which is to use Places API Autocomplete with specific parameters. That workaround works very well in Australia and many other countries with 4-digit postal codes.